# Sharing information between two XUL applications

Tags: javascript, xul

I am currently developing a toolbar and sidebar for firefox. I want to have the two share information, but upon loading the .js file I want them to share, it is loaded twice and has two instances instead of one.

How can I get the toolbar and the sidebar access the same information or global variables in a single javascript file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at localStorage :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage#localStorage

I use it for some web XUL applications. Quite easy to use.